# Jordan's Lemma for an integral

Tags: integration

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1} dx$$

Can Jordan's Lemma be applied this?

Comment: Any reason you want to use Jordan's Lemma over partial fractions?

Answer (score 1):

Well...not really, at least directly.  Jordan's lemma applies to functions of the form

$$f(z) = e^{i k z} g(z) $$

where the idea is that you want to find the conditions under which

$$\int_{C_R} dz \, f(z) $$

vanishes as $R \to \infty$, where $C_R$ is an arc of a circle of radius $R$ centered at the origin.

Your integral is not of the above form.  Rather, something called the "estimation lamma" applies, i.e., the magnitude of the integral around a circular arc is bounded by the max of the absolute value of the function on the arc times the length of the arc.